# NetworkManager corrupted ipv6 dns settings

Tags: debian, dns, gnome3, networkmanager, ipv6

Today, I started having most web sites failing to load in browsers.
Checking my network settings, I discovered those strange settings in ipv6 tab:
[image: buggy configuration]

Switching back to my usual dns for ipv6 (Google's one, `2001:4860:4860::8888` and `2001:4860:4860::8844`) solved my browsing issue.

But just to make sure, I then reopened the network settings: the same strange ipv4 addresses in my ipv6 dns configuration were back! Networking still works for now, but I fear the trouble will come back on next reboot.

The ipv4 tab has its expected settings.

The `/etc/resolv.conf` file was pointing my isp own ipv6 dns server, I have removed them.

`resolvconf` package is not installed.

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1` file looks fine.

```
[ethernet]
duplex=full

[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=231ba09e-7c56-4fb3-9df2-37cc0c4202b0
type=ethernet
timestamp=1480972453

[ipv6]
method=auto
dns=2001:4860:4860::8888;2001:4860:4860::8844;
ignore-auto-dns=true
ip6-privacy=2

[ipv4]
method=auto
dns=8.8.8.8;8.8.4.4;
ignore-auto-dns=true
```

`nm-connection-editor` interface shows the right settings.

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file does not contain any `supersede`.

Only the network configuration applet is wrong. I guess it is the `network-manager-gnome` interface. Its version on my system is `0.9.10.0-2` according to synaptic.
My distribution is a Debian Jessie, unattended updates activated (stable channel of course, it would not be a Jessie anymore otherwise, backports enabled), using gnome.

I search a bit randomly in my hidden home folders if some local settings were related to networking just in case, but found nothing, including in `~/.gconf/` folder.

What else should I check for that issue please?

### Follow up:

Thanks sourcejedi,
So the bad display looks like a bug, ipv6 addresses being displayed here as ipv4, using only first four bytes of them. Maybe this is just a display bug. But redefining my settings as I have done would then have overwritten the actual cause of the trouble...
I have reboot now, things still works for now (with display bug still here). No clue what was the actual trouble.
(Emptying the `resolv.conf` as I have done was undone at the next boot by the way, it was refilled with my isp ipv6 dns.)

Checking the nmap version on my system, it is `6.47-3+deb8u2`. But anyway, the old bug you found about it does not look related, just similar as you say.

Comment: Note this address is the first 4 bytes of the IPv6 address used for the DNS server.  (I googled the IPv4 address, which revealed a similar issue with nmap http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2010/q2/899).

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I was wondering if those invalid ipv4 addresses in ipv6 setting were the truncated ipv6 ones, but I got too lazy to remember ipv6 was in hex notation and have not performed the conversion...

Comment: Seeing this bug in Ubuntu GNOME 16.10 so it seems it's still not fixed. Does anyone know if it has even been (officially) reported yet?

Comment: It looks like it has been reported to [Red Hat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1121720) then closed un-handled (end of life of distro for which it was reported).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a likely cause. I was having `rdnssd` installed. This packing has a [know bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=740998) which causes it to override the dns settings...

I have removed it.

```
sudo apt-get remove rdnssd
```

As already later stated in the question, the bad display was just a bad display, not the actual cause of the trouble.